# Image mapping when hover price tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, css

How to map price tag on image like(something like image mapping), 
    please find the below screen shot link:

http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2156304/e6659de2c10638d4314a4d34924cec5e

```
thanks
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `absolute` positioned div and insert tag image in that. Then add an event listener which will open the popup when clicked on the div.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `css` to render red `border`, display data at `:hover` at `<img>` element at `content` property of `:after` pseudo element of adjacent `<content>` element, `position` set to `absolute` to display elements at specific position within viewport.

```css
#tag content {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  color: gold;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
}
#tag img:nth-of-type(1) ~ img {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  outline: thick solid red;
  padding: 16px;
}
#tag img:nth-of-type(1) ~ img:hover + content:after,
#tag img:nth-of-type(1) ~ content:hover:after {
  content: attr(data-tag);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px purple;
}
#tag img:nth-of-type(2),
#tag img:nth-of-type(2) + content {
  top: calc(17%);
  left: calc(66%);
}
#tag img:nth-of-type(3),
#tag img:nth-of-type(3) + content {
  top: calc(36%);
  left: calc(27%);
}
#tag img:nth-of-type(4),
#tag img:nth-of-type(4) + content {
  top: calc(95%);
  left: calc(7%);
}
```

```html
<div id="tag">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/300/nature" />
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/33/33/cats" class="tag" data-tag="cat1" />
  <content data-tag="cat1"></content>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/33/33/cats" class="tag" data-tag="cat2" />
  <content data-tag="cat2"></content>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/33/33/cats" class="tag" data-tag="cat3" />
  <content data-tag="cat3"></content>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks. also the positioned images are moving when responsive and page zoom out